# Updating paginated data in realtime with firebase and react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The issue I'm having is that whenever I try to update data contained within the paginated function, it doesn't update in realtime. They are only updated when the component is unmounted or when I refresh the page.
NB: the code inside the useEffect hook works as desired.
**

```
    useEffect(() => {
                const getSnapshot = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapShot) => {
                  const cmt = []
                  querySnapShot.forEach((dat) => {
                    cmt.push({ ...dat.data(), comment_id: dat.id })
                  })
                  setLastVisible(querySnapShot.docs[querySnapShot.docs.length - 1])
                  setComments(cmt)
                  setHasMorePages(true)
                })
                return () => getSnapshot()
              }, [])
// Paginated function
   const paginateData = async () => {
    setCommentLoad(true)
    const pageSize = 4
    const next = query(
      collection(db, `/posts/${post.post_id}/comments`),
      orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'),
      startAfter(lastVisible || 0),
      limit(pageSize)
    )

    await getDocs(next).then((docSnap) => {
      if (!docSnap.empty) {
        const cmt = []
        docSnap.forEach((snap) => {
          cmt.push({ ...snap.data(), comment_id: snap.id })
        })
        setComments((prev) => [...prev, ...cmt])
        if (docSnap?.docs[docSnap.docs.length - 1]) {
          setLastVisible(docSnap.docs[docSnap.docs.length - 1])
        }
        if (docSnap.docs.length < pageSize) setHasMorePages(false)
      }
    })

    setCommentLoad(false)
  }
```

**